# Error with repeated image_crop() with magick package

Tags: r, imagemagick

I am using the `magick` package to process some images. I need to crop them twice. The second time I crop, I get an error.

Here is a minimal working example example

```
library("magick")
library("magrittr")
img <- image_read(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"))
img %>% image_crop("50x76+50+0") %>% image_crop("10x76+0+0")
```

Which gives this error:

> Error in magick_image_crop(image, geometry) :
>     Magick: geometry does not contain image `/home/gbsrt/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/png/img/Rlogo.png' @ warning/transform.c/CropImage/574

I think I [understand](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_missed) why I am getting this error, and that I need to call `+repage`, but I cannot work out how to do this through the `magick` package.

Comment: Look for something like setPage(x,y) as the equivalent -page +0+0 in Imagemagick command line. Sorry I only know the command line in Imagemagick. But why do two crops. Can you not just figure out how to combine them into one crop? That should be equivalent to 10x76+50+0

Comment: I prefer two crops because I need to first remove some surrounding junk and then slice the remaining image into several parts. Cannot find anything like setPage in the package.

Comment: What is the link to this `magick` package? How does it relate to Imagemagcik? Is there documentation?  If so, is there a link to that?  Is there anything about `page` at all?

Comment: `magick` is on cran, also at github https://github.com/ropensci/magick. Documentation mainly links to imagemagick. Now fixed problem by writing wrapper to use single crop.

Comment: Did you solve it ?